# search files with .PDF extension in documents folder

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to search files with .PDF extension in documents folder.Have got this code where it returns and NSArray.My question is how to call this method and pass the desired extension example if i send parameter as PDF to this it should written all PDFS in Documents folder

I tried with following but it doesn't show the desired results and gives error no visible interface..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self findAllFiles:@"pdf"];

}

-(NSArray *)findAllFiles:(NSString *)extension
{
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *item;
    NSArray *contents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
    for (item in contents)
    {
        if ([[item pathExtension]isEqualToString:extension])
        {
            [matches addObject:item];
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

[image]

Comment: i checked this code and it works well for me.
check your documents folder contains pdf file.

Comment: @JincySam how do print  this  [self findFiles:@"pdf"];

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[self findAllFiles:@"pdf"]);

Comment: @JincySam it shows me 

the current folder name doesn't show any pdf in Documents as below--.    2015-08-12 19:02:15.905 pdf2jpg[3617:58171] (
)

Comment: u just manually add a pdf file in document Folder and then check, code is perfect

Comment: @JincySam i just added the screenshot to the question, can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking your device's documentFolder? For each stimulator it has a separate document folder. You can get that path using this code:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSHomeDirectory());//place this code in viewDidload
```

Place your pdf files in that folder.